# Can view in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) ever not be UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, the view in the arguments is UIView and most examples I see this being force unwrapped to UITableViewHeaderFooterView. I generally dislike force unwrapping unless I'm 100% sure this is impossible to be the class I'm force unwrapping. It seems that you can not set a section to anything other than UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Answer (score 0):

I believe UITableViewHeaderFooterView is a conveniently wrapped UIView that allows you to use reuseIdentifiers on the view to reuse the same instance (similar to how you would use a UITableViewCell). You can check out the documentation about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview). You'll notice that it's really just a UIView with some very simple subview structure and reuse conveniences.

You should be able to use a normal UIView (I've certainly done it before) for your header or footer, you just lose that extra convenience.